# PGF of a random variable $X$ .

Tags: probability

Is the probability generating function for a discrete random variable , $X$ of the distibution $B(1,p)$ , $(p+q)$ since $n = 1$.

i thought so?

Comment: The pgf of a Bernoulli variable $B(1,p)$ is $q+ps$

Answer (score 1):

As [JeanMarie](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/305862/jeanmarie) said in the comments, the PGF for a Binomial Random Variable, $X_n\sim\mathcal{Bin}(n,p)$, is: $$G_{X_n}(s) = \big(ps+(1-p)\big)^n\\= (ps+q)^n$$

So the PGF of a Bernoulli Random Variable, $X_1\sim\mathcal{Bin}(1,p)$, is: $$G_{X_1}(s) = ps+(1-p)\\= ps+q$$